# Why can zinc porphyrins assume 5 coordinate geometries?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

It has been reported that 5-coordinate geometries are possible and stable for Zn(II) porphyrin complexes. How do these complexes form and why are they stable when other 5-coordinate geometries of Zn(II) and other d10 metals are not stable?

Comment: First off, who reported it?  Second, is this really any different from PCl5 or SF6?

Comment: See for example 10.1021/ic50194a058

Comment: Honestly I don't know if its any different, I was hoping someone could give a quick rundown on how ligand field theory works in the d10 case where crystal field theory seems to suggest ligation would not occur, with a focus on how 5 coordinate geometries can emerge.